# How to solve this problem from running a new BaseGlobalPlanner in move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, move-base, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all, I wrote a global planner by modifying this [ompl_planner_base code](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_dturtle/sandbox/ompl_planner_base/src/) which is based on OMPL . The original code is an old style, so I modified it to run it in Hydro successfully. I also built it into move_base by following [this instruction](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) on ROS wiki. Everything worked fine.  But when launch the move_base node, some errors came out:

```
  [FATAL] [1406215304.849099962]: Failed to create the planner_rrtstar/turtlebot_rrtstar planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: Failed to load library /home/turtlebot/moveit/devel/lib//libplanner_rrtstar.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/turtlebot/moveit/devel/lib//libplanner_rrtstar.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN4ompl4base13SO2StateSpaceE)
[move_base-7] process has died [pid 9966, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/move_base/move_base cmd_vel:=mobile_base/commands/velocity __name:=move_base __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/369f7f02-1346-11e4-9fc2-40f02f3a602b/move_base-7.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/369f7f02-1346-11e4-9fc2-40f02f3a602b/move_base-7*.log
```

The libplanner_rrtstar.so has been generated in /moveit/devel/lib/libplanner_rrtstar.so, so what is the problem?
Has anyone encountered same problem before? Any advices are appreciated.
Thank you!

Thank @David lu and @Ken_in_JAPAN!
By  adding "

```
 target_link_libraries(
     planner_rrtstar
     ${catkin_LIBRARIES} 
     ${OMPL_LIBRARIES} 
     base_local_planner
)
```

" in CMAKElist.txt
The above errors disappear. But after modifying CMAKElist.txt, other errors came out by running catkin_make:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbase_local_planner
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/turtlebot/moveit/devel/lib/libplanner_rrtstar.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [planner_rrtstar/CMakeFiles/planner_rrtstar.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I don't know what "cannot find -lbase_local_planner" means. The libbase_local_planner.so is already underneath /opt/ros/hydro/lib
Please give me advice again. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187705/how-to-solve-this-problem-from-running-a-new-baseglobalplanner-in-move_base/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-26**:
I recommend you to post your problem on another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think what @David Lu says is correct. I recommend you check what the error of undefined symbol is. I encountered such an error. This page might be useful for you. ( http://answers.ros.org/question/174486/about-undefined-symbol-error/?answer=174606#post-id-174606 )

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-07-24**:
Thank you very much, It is very helpful.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-25**:
@scopus, Error `/usr/bin/ld: can't find -` is written on this page. (http://answers.ros.org/question/50120/catkin-conversion-usrbinld-cannot-find-lpackage_name/). Please check it out!

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-07-25**:
Thank you. But it is different situation in my problem . In My CMakelist.txt, target_link_libraries is shown as above.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-07-25**:
I'm sorry, I have never looked at the error. I use one c++ file and one include file only. I mean that I refer the sample of ompl, but I don't use it. I don't use SO2StateSpace().

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is not with your configuration, but with how you are building the planner. The key bit is `undefined symbol: _ZTVN4ompl4base13SO2StateSpaceE`. Are you linking ompl correctly?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1